# Why does not Play Framework reload assets?

Tags: scala, playframework

I started my play app in dev mode and tried to change the index html file but play did not update it.
My app only consists with assets in public folder and order to see changes i have to restart my app. My observations have shown that play compiles assets in `target/web/public/main` directory and does not update it when file in `public` directory is changed

How should i configure my app in order to all assets are reloaded when i change it?

Comment: It development mode files in the public assets folder should reflect changes. But usually one would use some template (Play uses Twirl as it's template language).

Comment: it should but it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really stupid problem. One of my subproject contained configuration `scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value` it just overrided original `scalaSource` in `Compile`. The problem was solved by changing to `scalaSource in ThisScope := baseDirectory.value`.

Comment: Great, that worked for me, even though I don't get why.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers will cache the assets in your public folder, so while the Play server will be serving the new content, you will still be seeing the old content. If you are using Chrome you can clear the caches by performing a hard reload(Ctrl+Shift+R) which will force it to get all the content from the server again.

An even better solution is to use asset fingerprinting which you can find information about [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#Reverse-routing-and-fingerprinting-for-public-assets). This basically means that the names of your assets will change when their contents change, so your browser will be aware that it needs to download the new file rather than serve the cached one. To do this is pretty simple- in your routes file, change

```
GET  /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

to

```
GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

and when you need to refer to an asset, instead of using Assets.at, use Assets.versioned ie.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

However as Kris said in his comment, if you were to use the twirl template system(with your index page being in app/views/index.scala.html, rather than have it as an asset in your public folder) Play will recompile your templates after any change and serve the new page.

Comment: Firstly, it is not a cache because cache issue i tested immediately. Secondly, i do not use template engines. Thirdly, i used `GET / controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="/view/index.html")` route and `GET / controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file="/view/index.html")
GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file)` does not work.

Comment: Great. I also had a similar problem and your solution worked like a charm. It was really annoying having to recompile several times to find a non-existing bug, later to find out that the problem is due to the fact that the changes I made are not reflected in the browser because of caching.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to wait a little while for play to detect the file change, try to refresh the page several times to see if it works

Also if you are running Play in a special environment, like running the code linked to a Docker container from MacOS, you need [some special settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634534/osx-play-framework-auto-reload) to the file change listener of Play to make the detection work.

Comment: I'm using play inside a docker container on MacOSX.. which special setting have you in mind?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634534/osx-play-framework-auto-reload